How to control the speed of fan in Argon ONE (v2) Pi 4 case on Debian 64-bit?
On Raspberry Pi OS, the original Argon ONE (v2) Pi 4 script just works, link to GitHub:
curl https://download.argon40.com/argon1.sh | bash

On Debian 12 Bookworm 64-bit, however, it does not, by default at least. How to fix it or control the fan directly?


First, I installed curl and wget, both of which the original script seemed to require.

Then I ran the script with:
curl https://download.argon40.com/argon1.sh | bash

It might have been unnecessary, but it also installed a bunch of stuff, presumably needed for operation.

According to the instructions on this GitHub page, I enabled the following two modules:
echo i2c-bcm2835 >> /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
echo i2c-dev >> /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf


Rebooted, and went on testing while leaving the original Argon script installed (possibly to play with it later on):
i2cset -y 3 0x01a 0x00  # fan stop
i2cset -y 3 0x01a 0x64  # fan full




I also wrote a tiny POSIX shell script to prettify and output the current temperature of Pi's CPU:
#!/bin/sh

# Show temperature of this Pi's CPU in green/red color.

set -o nounset -o errexit

# read the raw CPU temperature value, i.e. integer
# multiplied by 1000 to accomodate 3 decimal spaces
cpu_temp_raw=$( cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp )

# divide the raw value by 1000, and cut the decimal places for only one
cpu_temp_processed=$( echo "scale=1; $cpu_temp_raw / 1000" | bc )

# choose color for the output
if [ "$cpu_temp_raw" -lt 40000 ]; then
    # bright green
    output_color=$( tput setaf 2 )
else
    # bright red
    output_color=$( tput setaf 1 )
fi

# show the output in bold and in the above color
tput bold; echo "CPU Temperature: $output_color$cpu_temp_processed"; tput sgr0

The script above you may copy/modify as you please. Being its name pi-temp, you could easily monitor temperature e.g. every 10 seconds with:
while true; do ./pi-temp && sleep 10s; done

Image for the words ;)

